# Set delay for the second click function jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the second click function to be delayed by 500ms, where do I insert this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropToggler').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass("open");
  });
    $('.acceptCta').click(function() {      //I want the delay on this function.
    $(this).parent().removeClass("open");
  });
});
```

Tried this too, didn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropToggler').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass("open");
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.acceptCta').click(function() {
      $(this).parent().removeClass("open");
    });
  }, 800);
});
```

Comment: Read this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: do you want to delay the removeClass call or hooking up the click event itself?

Comment: @henokg I want to delay the removeClass which is triggered by a click. So when I click the given button ```.acceptCta```, the removeClass function is delayed.

Comment: ```setTimeout(function() {$(this).parent().removeClass("open");},800);```
use this as the clicklistener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delegate and tell which element you are referring to when clicking and use that for `setTimeout` - `removeClass` function

`var $this = $(this)` // will be click function

`setTimeout(function() {}` does not know what is `$(this)` as we searching for the parents of the `clicked` event element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropToggler').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass("open");
  });
    $('.acceptCta').click(function() { 
     //This needed
      var $this = $(this)
      //delay removeClass
      setTimeout(function() {
        $this.parent().removeClass("open");
      }, 800);
    });
});
```

Comment: This is the only solution which worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @R.Srour Glad that i could help. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

```js
setTimeout(function(){ 
    //your code goes here
   alert("Hello"); 
}, 3000);//here you can set the time in milliseconds
```

you can use the [setTimeout Function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: I know that, but where do I put it in? I've tried, it didn't work.

Comment: Please don't post an answer that is primarily a link. Consider giving an example?

Comment: @R.Srour please share that.

Comment: @R.Srour Better read the tutorial again. `.click(() => setTimeout(() => $(this).parent().removeClass("open")), 500)`

Comment: @evolutionxbox I tried this:
```$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropToggler').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass("open");
  });
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('.acceptCta').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("open");
  });
}, 800);
});```

Comment: @R.Srour please add this to the original question?